# Rails low level cache not working in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I've configured the development.rb file like this:

```
# Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

config.cache_store = :memory_store
config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
}
```

(erased the default config that checks for a file just to test)

Then I open a `rails console` to test this but it does not seem to be working:

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.cache.write("asd", "asd")
=> true
[2] pry(main)> Rails.cache.read("asd")
=> nil
```

I've managed to make it work a couple of days ago, but now it is not working.

A I missing something?

Comment: `database.rb` ?, aren't you talking about your `config/environments/development.rb` file ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo. I'll update it.

Comment: are you using rails 5 ?, is it a new app ?, if so, do you have this line `if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?` in your `config/environments/development.rb` file ?

Comment: I've deleted that line. I left the development.rb file as I said in my post.
it is rails 5.1.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by restarting spring. Doing

```
> spring stop
Spring stopped.
> spring start
```

does the trick.

Note: when starting spring again, it may fail, but it'll work anyway.

Comment: I have to restart rails server too, and now works :)

Answer (score 11):

In rails `6.1.4`

run `rails dev:cache` to toggle caching in development